# Why this SQL Query does not show zeroes COUNT function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing a simply intranet quiz engine for my company and I want when the user comes to the START page of the quiz to see the total number of participants in his division. If there is no participants in one of the quizzes, the following Query should display zero, but right now it does not show zeroes and I don't know why:

```
SELECT     dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut AS Division, COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.UserQuiz.Username) AS [Number of Participants]
FROM         dbo.Divisions INNER JOIN
                      dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode INNER JOIN
                      dbo.UserQuiz ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.UserQuiz.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Quiz ON dbo.UserQuiz.QuizID = dbo.Quiz.QuizID
WHERE     (dbo.Quiz.QuizID = @QuizID) AND (dbo.Employee.Username = @Username)
GROUP BY dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut
```

So How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need an outer join to account for the case where nobody in your division has taken a quiz yet.

```
SELECT 
    Division = d.DivisionShortcut, 
    [Number of Participants] = COUNT(DISTINCT uq.Username)
FROM dbo.Divisions AS d
INNER JOIN dbo.Employee AS e
ON d.SapCode = e.DivisionCode 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UserQuiz AS uq
ON e.Username = uq.Username 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Quiz AS q
ON uq.QuizID = q.QuizID
AND dbo.Quiz.QuizID = @QuizID 
WHERE e.Username = @Username
GROUP BY d.DivisionShortcut;
```

Comment: Also, if one of the employees in the Division participates in one of the available quizzes, this query will show the number of participants as 1 in all quizzes even if there is no participants.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results, so we don't have to guess.